# flutter method channel always throws MissingPluginException [Android]

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-platform-channel

I have this `platform-specific` code which uses the `MethodChannel`, and it always throws a `MissingPluginException`, although the implementation is already exists in `Android` main activity file!

MainActivity.kt file (Android):
[image]

engage_service.dart file (Flutter):
[image]

error:
[image]

Anyone can help identifying the problem here? it would really mean a lot!!

Comment: I can't see anything wrong in the code. Did you try to terminate the app and run again? Native side changes don't persist with hot reload.

Comment: @Ryosuke i tried to do that, but still throws the same exception, i also cleaned the project, uninstalled the app but still remain in the same error!!

Comment: If it is just a demo kind of project, then maybe you can paste a github link to it. Also make sure that you didn't open `android` folder of some other project in Android Studio. That happens a lot.

Comment: @Ryosuke unfortunately it's a big project, i tried to share the most important code of it, also i just check out that the code is written under the app android module so it should 100% work but this is so weird!!

Comment: Yes its weird for sure. One last thing I could think of is, where are you calling `PlatformSpecificCode().register` from? If it is being called before `runApp` method, you need to call `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` before calling `PlatformSpecificCode().register`.

Comment: @Ryosuke im calling it after the runApp, in some StatefulWidget's initState, i literally have no clue why in the name of heaven is not working :')

Comment: @Ryosuke maybe there's something i should do to register this platform code? or notify the android about it? idk for sure.. the GeneratedPluginRegistrant provides nothing but the ones i used in pubspec.yaml file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248651/discussion-between-ryosuke-and-devmuaz).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the help of this incredible guy @Ryosuke,

What I was doing is using this activity `com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioServiceActivity` which belongs to this package [just_audio_background](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio_background) as the main activity in the `AndroidManifest.xml` instead of the `MainActivity`.

So I replaced it with the `MainActivity` and then in the `MainActivity` I changed its extension which was `FlutterActivity` with `AudioServiceActivity` since this class itself extends the `FlutterActivity`.

Thank You @Ryosuke

Answer (score 0):

Also, in your invokeMethodCall, you have to include your channel name as a prefix to the name of the function you're invoking i.e. "_invokeMethodCall("$_channelName/register", args...)" otherwise it won't recognise which method belonging to which channel you're trying to call.